# Changing temporary/default save location

Tags: windows-vista, microsoft-excel-2007

At a work place with 60 something employees a user (Vista computer, Excel 2007) is finding that when she attempts to open Excel files directly from a mail or Internet Explorer it says the disc is full and she can't open the file. If she first manually saves the document to the computer then opens it, it works. The disc is not full.

By default her Excel is attempting to store and then open this Excel file somewhere she doesn't have writing/editing rights. I suspect probably one of the many network drives she has reading rights from.

How do I check where Excel tries to save her file when attempting to open it directly through the browser and how do I change that?

Comment: Try clicking the "Office Button" > "Excel Options" > "Save" and check the directories there?

Comment: hey Jerry thx..

I realized that it could probably also be her temporary internet files that has issue, considering its through the explorer she doesn't get to open the files.

So I first of all tried to change the location you link to, to a folder I made on the desktop
Then I changed the temporary internet files to the same folder on desktop.. still won't open.

A lot looks wrong here, it also 'according to her' often tells her that her temporary internet files have been cleared, without her ordering it.

Answer (score 0):

i'm sure your only way to do this is through editing your registry file.
You could see how to do this in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms940828(v=winembedded.5).aspx) or in [here to](http://www.rtwincustomize.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=570:how-to-change-system-temporary-directory-via-registry&catid=59:windows-seven-tutorials&Itemid=143).

Don't forget to backup your registry before. Hope this could help you :)

Ps. To open registry, you could open from window command run(Window+R) and type regedit